# Incorrect label with groupby matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, label

I have a plot and I would like to correct labels for plot lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=['Date'],sep=';', 
dayfirst=True)
print(df)
```

[image: data]

```
car = df.Car.unique()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)

for ix, cars in enumerate(car):

    df[df['Car'] == cars].groupby(['Combustible']).plot(x='Date', 
                                  y='Cost', ax = ax[ix], 
                                  title="Cars: "+ cars, figsize=(10,8), 
                                 )
```

[image: Plot]

How can I display the correct label combustible by car? Is possible to plot without looping for, like `ggplot` face wrap function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
for ix, cars in enumerate(car):
    for l,g in df[df['Car'] == cars].groupby('Combustible'):
        g.plot(x='Date', label=l,
                                  y='Cost', ax = ax[ix],
                                  title="Cars: "+ cars, figsize=(10,8),
                                 )
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use seaborn and utilize the `hue` function

```
import seaborn as sns

for ix, cars in enumerate(car):
    p = sns.pointplot(x='Date',y='Cost',data=df[df['Car'] == cars], hue='Combustible', ax=ax[ix], figsize=(10,8))
    p.set_title('Cars: ' + cars)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! I'm trying to plot with only one loop. I have a code in R for this example, and ggplot is easier than matplotlib. 'Color' and 'Facet wrap' are good features to plot. Isn't there equivalent in matplotlib?

Comment: AFAIK neither matplotlib or ggplot in python have anything like facet_wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Using factorplot seaborn code is simpler:

```
sns.factorplot(x='Date', y = 'Cost', data=df, hue='Combustible', col="Car")
```

However, the performance is terrible! I have a dataframe with 85000 row and my computer can't plot it

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the best and simplest way:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Car", hue="Combustible", size=12)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "Date", "Cost")
```